# VS Code perforce extension snyc

Tags: visual-studio-code, perforce

Can I select a version when I sync a file from vscode perforce extension? I was wondering if I can select a version when I right click on a file and then click on Perforce>sync. I know how to sync with Command.

Click sync and it will sync to the latest version
What should I do?

Comment: This is just IMHO, but I'd recommend using either `p4` or P4V for the times you need to do anything outside the basic sync-edit-submit workflow.  If you're syncing to an old revision you probably want to also be able to see the history (with `p4 filelog`/Revision History/Revision Graph/Time-Lapse View/etc) and there's a limit to how much you can do within an IDE extension.

Comment: I use VSCode but I *only* use the extension to do `p4 edit`, and only since it's easier to find the file I want to edit in VSCode (since I probably already have it open there) than it is to find it in either CMD or P4V.  Almost everything else (even `p4 sync`) I do at the command line.